# Clearing Boost cache with drush

Tags: drush, caching

I am testing the boost module out, it is a great performance enhancement for the site I am working on.

However I would like to be able to get boost to clear it's cache using drush. `Drush cc all` doesn't seem to do this. And looking in the boost module code, there doesn't seem to be a cron command for it. Am I missing something or is this currently not implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. I was missing something.

Boost is a bit more fussy about the URL than the rest of drush when clearing the cache

```
drush --uri=http://my.site.name cc all
```

will work.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to clear Boost's cache and not any other caches:

`drush --uri=http://example.com boost-cache-clear-all`

See also [the notes at the Drush integration patch for Boost](http://drupal.org/node/517962).

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like this is only in the dev release of boost for the moment, but still good to know.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed that since my patch got committed to the dev branch, that it had made its way into an official release. That only works if there's an official release after the commit. You could probably use the Drush include file, renaming it to remove the underscore, from the "patch" but still use the official release of Boost, since there are no changes to Boost necessary for the Drush functionality to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [drush aliases](https://www.drupal.org/node/1401522) configured, just do this:
    drush @name_of_alias cc all

I'm using Drush 8 and Drupal 7, but this also worked on my earlier versions.